# How target first Paragraph tag in body with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, paragraph

I want to add the class "lead" to the first paragraph tag on every page on my website. Only the first instance should be targeted. The structure of each page is different. Here's how I want to code to function.

```
<body>
<div><div><p class="lead"></p></div></div>
<div><div><div><div><p></p></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><p></p><p></p></div></div>
<p></p>
<div><p></p></div>
</body>
```

I've tried several variations of the code below and can't get the code to work.

This code will target to the first paragraph and other random paragraphs.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body p:first-child').addClass('lead');
        });
    });
```

this code does nothing

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body p:first').addClass('lead');
        });
    });
```

Comment: try $('body p:first-of-type') first-of-type is more specific and will match the first occurrence of a specified element, even if it doesn't come absolutely first in the HTML.[css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/)

Comment: Or  $('body').find("p:first").addClass('lead');

Comment: you could do `$($('p')[0]).addClass('lead')`

Comment: You sure jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body p:first').addClass('lead');
        });
    }); did not work for you? It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Using $('body p:first-of-type') worked!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastTagIndex = $('body').find('p').length - 1
  $('body').find('p').eq(0).addClass('lead');
  $('body').find('p').eq(lastTagIndex).addClass('last');
});
```

```css
.lead {
  color: red;
}

.last {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>5</p>
  <div>
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

You could use `find` and `eq` to implement.